# Is there any declarative way to check validity of input parameters in C# REST service controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have a controller class with the following method

```
public async Task<XYZ> ProcessSomeAPICall(User u, int a, string b, bool c) {
    if (u.Name == "Bubba" && a < 10) {
        throw new BubbaException("there is no way Bubba can do more then 10")
    }

    if (u.Position == null && !c) {
        throw new EmploymentException("user without a job should have c set up")
    }

    //... more input parameter checks here

    return await executeSomeApplicationLogic(u, a, b, c);
}
```

Is there any framework that helps me minimize the amount of conditional code I need to write in order to perform parameter checks?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FluentValidation for validate your inputs and increase readability .

```
 public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<XYZ> ProcessSomeAPICall(RegisterUserCommand command)  // command => user in your sample
    {
        command.Validate();
    }
}

public class RegisterUserCommand

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    // some properties

    public void Validate()
    {
        new RegisterUserCommandValidator().Validate(this).RaiseExceptionIfNeed();
    }
}

public class RegisterUserCommandValidator : AbstractValidator
{
    public RegisterUserCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p=> p.UserName).NotEmpty().NotNull().WithMessage("some-message");
    }
}
```